# Error when pass variable values to new Activity on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vinicius.chatandroid/com.example.vinicius.chatandroid.Janela}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference;

code:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    EditText ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtIp);
    EditText porta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPorta);
    String txtIp = ip.getText().toString();
    String pota = porta.getText().toString();
    int txtPorta = Integer.parseInt(pota);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Janela.class);
    intent.putExtra("ip", txtIp);
    intent.putExtra("porta", txtPorta);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

new activity

```
public Janela() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String ip = intent.getStringExtra("ip");
    int porta = intent.getIntExtra("porta",0);
    this.conexao = new Conexao(ip, porta);
    conexao.addObserver(this);
    escreve("Chat iniciado com " + conexao.getIp() + ":" + conexao.getPorta());
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String , it seems you are calling getString... on null reference.

Answer (score 2):

`getIntent()` would return null before `onCreate()` is called, so `intent` is becoming null in your code (Called in constructor) which is causing `NPE`.

Using constructor in activity is not a good idea, it has its own life cycle and you should follow that.

**Solution:**

Change method `public Janela() {` to something like `public void MyJanela() {` and call it inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thank worked did not think the mistake was that

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 dat english tho :D (not yours, obviously)

Answer (score 1):

Never do anything in the constructor of an activity or Fragment, try the following code :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String ip = intent.getStringExtra("ip");
        int porta = intent.getIntExtra("porta",0);
        this.conexao = new Conexao(ip, porta);
        conexao.addObserver(this);
        escreve("Chat iniciado com " + conexao.getIp() + ":" + conexao.getPorta());
       }
```